# How do i get a time spent to resolve a logged query/call which is stored on SQL Database?

Tags: c#

I am writing an application in C#, I need to track down the time from when the user log a call until the call is resolved. The timer should start to count when the call is accepted and stops when the call is resolved. This timer should not count during weekend. I don't know if this makes sense. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need a timer, you need math.

Comment: Hi.. please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks

Comment: You store two timestamps. One when the call starts and another when it's resolved. You subtract the two to get the time spent (also subtracting any time you don't want to count like weekends or holidays).